# __construct function not working

Tags: php, static

Public function __construct is not working. please help me. thank you

**php**

```
class vp_session
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (session_id() == '' || session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE || !isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public static function setSession($key, $value)
    {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function getSession($key)
    {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }

    public static function removeSession($name)
    {
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }

    public static function sessionDestroy()
    {
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

**Calling**
vp_session::setSession("user_id", "$this->user_id");

**error** 
Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: `session_start();` Has to be before your using the `array`! So you can't check things from the array if you didn't started it!

Comment: ya thats why i add it in __construct funciton. but construct is not working

Comment: Could you please give any further information where the error exactly occurs?

Comment: call session_start(); in the starting of file

Answer (score 4):

You are using static method(s).
So if you call:

```
vp_session::removeSession();
```

Your constructor will not be called automatically. You should either:

1. Istanciate a `new vp_session()` object, or:
2. Don't use static methods.